# Possible to auto-check "Open in new window" for inserting links in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm looking for a way to auto-check the box for "Open in new window" when inserting a link using the Insert tab in the site ribbon of SharePoint 2010.

Is there a way to configure this in the SharePoint settings available through the browser? If not, are there steps I could take in SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to set this setting in any easy way.

You will need to either use Javascript to always check this checkbox, or use a delegate control enabled on all sites.